# What is the tag question of "None but X can help us."?

Tags: question-tags

What is the question tag of "None but Allah can help us."? Is it "can any?" or is it "can they?" or something else?

More compact : What is the question tag of "No one can help us."?

Core of this Post is : Does "None" go with "any" or "they" or something else ?

Comment: Of course you could just say “Right?”

Answer (score 3):

The question tag for "None but X can help us" is "..., can they?" according to [www.eslbase.com](https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/tag-questions) and [open.books4languages.com](https://open.books4languages.com/english-b2-grammar/chapter/nobody-nothing-and-somebody-question-tags/) and other similar web-sites.

Use "it" when there is "nothing" or "everything" ; Use "they" when there is "no one" or "everyone".

Comment: I'd agree but contend that "they" is correct only because the gender (if any) of the agency who can help is unknown, not because the agency is plural. It's analagous to "A member of staff will meet you, they will be car." Although "none" is often used with a plural pronoun ("None of the items are ready for despatch", "None of the children are ready to go home" for example) strictly speaking 'none' is a contraction of 'not one' and so is singular. The examples above should, strictly speaking, take the singular form of the verb giving "...is ready for despatch" and "...is ready to go home".

Comment: @BoldBen , https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/none/ says "None" can be Singular or Plural or Both !! Here, "they" is used because "None" == "not one" == "Zero" & hence "Zero Individuals [[ Plural ]] can help us" & hence we use "they" in the Question tag.